# How to Shuffle two Objects in javascript which has an Id and value in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, fabricjs, shuffle

Well i been doing some research on it i have one Object in javascript and i have made copy of it i have to shuffle both the objects data's. I dont want both the objects in same order.

I need to shuffle it.

I have shuffled it in different manner using another array with having only id, same id in it as in testArra,that way i have made an array which does not have these id but has id which starts from 0. 
Please help me with this.

the method i have used was : -

```
var testIndexshuffleData = testShuffle(indexNumberOne);
function testShuffle(arra1){
    for (var i = 0; i < arra1.length - 1; i++) {
        var j = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (arra1.length - i));

        var temp = arra1[j];
        arra1[j] = arra1[i];
        arra1[i] = temp;
    }
    return arra1;
}

var newArray = shuffleArraytest(testArray,testIndexshuffleData);
function shuffleArraytest(arrayOneName,arrayTwoIndex){
    var newTextArray = [];
        var arrayTwoIndexLength = arraytwoIndex.length;
        console.info("length of an array : "+arrayTwoIndexLength);
        for(let i = 0; i < arrayTwoIndexLength;i++){
            var indexSave = arraytwoIndex[i];   
            var arrayOneNameSingleIndex = arrayOneName[indexSave];
            newTextArray.push(arrayOneNameSingleIndex);

        }

    return newTextArray;
}

var testArray = ({
        30 : 'hello everyone',
        31 : 'i hope',
        32 : 'you all,
        33 : 'are',
        34 : 'fine',
    });
var testArrayTwo = testArray;
```

it should shuffle in any manner like.
33:'you all',31:'i hope',34:'fine',30:'hello everyone',32:'you all'

Comment: Is there a reason you're using objects instead of actual arrays? Your keys are numeric and consecutive anyway; using arrays would make this much easier.

Comment: `var testArray = ({ 30 : 'hello everyone', 31 : 'i hope', 32 : 'you all, 33 : 'are', 34 : 'fine', }); ` is not an array, can your post you exact need as an output ? array ? object with prop ? array of object ?

Comment: well this is comming in JSON format i have to use this key's in game for validaton in many ways otherwise i would have opt for array since my game using a voice data as well so i have to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that is not an array that is an Object. If you want to keep the object, you have to transform it into an array

```js
var testArray = ({ 30 : 'hello everyone', 31 : 'i hope', 32 : 'you all', 33 : 'are', 34 : 'fine', });
var tempArray = Object.values(testArray)
var newArray = tempArray.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
console.log(newArray)
```

If you want to keep the keys you can change your object to an array of object

```js
var testArray = ([{ 30 : 'hello everyone'}, {31 : 'i hope'},{ 32 : 'you all'}, {33 : 'are'}, {34 : 'fine'}]);
var newArray = testArray.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Well thank you i was looking for this i had tried different method which does not provied me the keys which are very important for me. Will try this now.

Comment: glad to help @shubhranshus don't forget to validate the answer if it works

Comment: well this method worked like a charm now i can go with this method thank you @Sylvain Attoumani

Answer (score 0):

I think you could generate random id and using it as a reference pull the object from the array and push it to the new array, that should work

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing several issues with this code. The first issue is that you appear to have confused an array and an object.

An object is essentially a map to where data is located. It has two components: keys and attributes. Your 'testArray' is an object, and will not behave as an array. Your keys are all numbers, and the way you've written the array, it won't compile. You would need to make your keys into strings `var testArray = ({'30': 'hello everyone'})` or you would need to write out a key that starts with a letter. `var testArray = ({thirty: 'hello everyone'})`

An array would be declared with square brackets, and would be something like this:

```
var myArray = ["hello everyone','i hope','you all','are','fine']
```

An array is just a list of data. Each element has something called in index, which starts at 0, and tells us where an element is in an array. In this example, 'hello everyone' is at index 0. 'i hope' is at index 1, 'you all' is at index 2, etc. You can use the index of an array to return the element that you want. If I write out

```
console.log(myArray[3]) //'are'
```

I will receive the string 'are', because it is the third element of the array. I can also use this technique to re-assign values in an array.

```
myArray[4] = 'excellent'
console.log(myArray) // 'hello everyone','i hope','you all','are','doing','excellent'
```

For what you're looking to do, it sounds like you should use a helper variable to swap values between array indexes. Example:

```
let helperVar = myArray[2]
Array[2] = myArray[5]
myArray[5] = helperVar
console.log(myArray)
// 'hello everyone','i hope','fine','are','you all'
```